# What is the correct src= attribute to load scripts from node.js server

Tags: javascript, html, node.js

Both my `p5.js` and `sketch.js` scripts will not load.

My `index.html` is loaded by `Node.js`

I think I am misusing the `src` value in my`<script>` tag in the HTML. 
My `p5.js` script is up one level and in a folder called `P5`, and my `sketch.js` file is in a folder called `P5Scripts` in the same directory as this `index.html` file.

In the chrome console, I get this message :
`Loading failed for the <script> with source “http://45.76.140.199:3000/P5/p5.js”.`

and

`Loading failed for the <script> with source “http://45.76.140.199:3000/P5Scripts/sketch.js”.`

I can see that my `src` attribute is wrong, but what would be the correct way to load these scripts?

`index.html:`

```
<!doctype html>
<html>
    <head>
        <title>My Website</title>
    </head>

    <script src="../P5/p5.js"></script>
    <script src="P5Scripts/sketch.js"></script>

    <body>
    </body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There isn't a way to bind nodejs with the DOM elements of your html because nodejs is backend and html DOM elements are frontend.

Since you are trying to modify the html, chances are that what you really want is to use plain javascript which would run on the browser.

Nodejs is a backend technology which runs on the server. At the time the html is displayed nodejs has already done its work and isn't aware of what is going on the page unless [AJAX](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ajax_(programming)) involved.

Have a brief look to client/server model [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Client%E2%80%93server_model).

Comment: I basically want Node.js to eventually trigger events in P5, but for now I just want to load p5 onto the screen :)

Comment: From the html you are going to use just plain javascript. Then you will handle your trigger events with ajax from the frontend and send the needed information to the backend. Then and only then is nodejs' time.